# how to remove the auto padding in nativescript android actionbar?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I tried to add two colors with full width in nativescript android. But it always takes extra padding. Below is my code-

```
<ActionBar class="p-l-0 m-l-0" backgroundColor="#007FA3">
    <GridLayout rows="auto,auto" columns="*">

        <StackLayout class="p-2" row="0" style="background-color: #F29F03;" horizontalAlignment="left">
            <Label class="action-label p-2" width="200%" text=" Please wait" fontSize="12" color="white" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" row="1">
            <label textAlignment="center" text="&#xf060; " class="fas" row="1" color="white"></label>
            <Label text="PageTitle" fontSize="22" color="white" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</ActionBar>
```

How to remove the extra margin before orange label?

[image: my code output]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a later version of Theme then you may need to increase the css specificity, such as:

```
.ns-root ActionBar.actionbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

And in your xml file,

```
<ActionBar class="actionbar" backgroundColor="#007FA3">
...
```

Comment: Hi @David, thanks for the solution but it's still not working!

Comment: OK, sorry to hear that.  That was the source for many such woes for me recently as I migrated my app from 6.x to 8.x.